# Submitting a form when a popup is closed

Tags: javascript, forms

I've written a code which displays the list of quizzes and when one is selected a new window is  popped up and the online quiz runs. The problem is, when the window is closed the timer should expire i.e the form should be submitted before the window is closed. The code to generate a new window is as follows :

```
 var radios = document.getElementsByName("quizname");
var flag=0;
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) 
{       
    if (radios[i].checked) 
    {
        flag=1;
        var x=radios[i].value;
        var z=radios[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==0)
{
    alert("Choose an option!!");
    exit;
}
var x="http://127.0.0.1/example/timedrunquiz.php?y="+x;
var win=window.open(x,z,"fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=yes");
win.focus();
```

I used `win.onbeforeunload` but I am unable to complete the task. What should I do to submit the form before closing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a code you tried in `win.onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: There is nothing!! after `win.focus()` I called `win.onbeforeunload`!! like `win.onbeforeunload = submitForm();`  @YuriyGalanter

Comment: If `submitForm()` is your function that submits the form you should assign it to `onbeforeunload` without () like this: `win.onbeforeunload = submitForm;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way to go about it. You should have a submit button on the window with a listener that could call `win.close();` after the submission is complete.

Now, to be sure that the user actually submits anything you should rather use the `win.onbeforeunload` to ask for confirmation if the user really wants to close the page, like this:

```
win.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return confirm('Do you really want to exit? All your progress would be lost');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit form before closing you can use ajx to submit form

```
 function callback()
    {
        $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "yourUrl",
                   data: 'YourData',


         });
        return "You are about to leave this page"; 
    }

    win.onbeforeunload = callBack;
```